# Tried to change store URL and now can't access Store

Tags: magento-1.7

I have run the following queries on MySql:

> 1. SELECT config_id FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
>
> Taken this config_id for #2
>
> 2. UPDATE core_config_data SET value = "online-rug-store" WHERE config_id = 6;
> 3. SELECT config_id FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/secure/base_url';
> 4. UPDATE core_config_data SET value = "online-rug-store" WHERE config_id = 7;

And now I can't access my Magento store or admin page on either my-site.com/magento or my-site.com/online-rug-store

Is there anything I can do at this point to gain access?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? How? Please share the details with us. Thanks!

Comment: I changed my hosting company and they did it for me so my problem is solved but not by me.  If I had to guess I think my problem was that I changed my site url in the sql but not in the folder structure.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE core_config_data
SET `value` = 'http://my-site.com/online-rug-store/'
WHERE PATH LIKE '%base_url'
```

Note that you need the full URL and a trailing slash. If you have SSL setup for your domain (particularly for use with the admin) then you will need to update the `secure_base_url` path separately.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't yet have an SSL certificate so I won't need to set it up separately now. However, after trying this, I go to http://my-site.com/online-rug-store/ in my browser and I get Magento's 404 error. Would I have to clear the cache somehow to be able to view my admin panel and store again?

Comment: delete the contents of [magento root]/var/cache

Comment: I tried that, and var/session as well.

Comment: Is there some sort of test I can do to see if some other part of the site works?

Comment: Before, I used to go to my-site.com/magento. After updating core_config_data to 'http://my-site.com/online-rug-store/' when I go to http://my-site.com/magento, it redirects to 'http://my-site.com/online-rug-store/' and returns a 404 error.

Comment: When I tried updating core_config_data back to 'http://my-site.com/magento' it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

**Number 1 rule of Magento - don't edit the DB directly.

Number 2 rule of Magento - seriously, don't edit the DB directly.**
<sup>Chuck Norris is excluded from these rules of course</sup>

We don't normally advocate re-running the installer just to change the URL, in fact its a horrible practice, but in this situation, its your easiest solution.

Remove/rename `app/etc/local.xml` and launch the site from the base URL and re-run the installer.

It should correct any mistakes you've made from editing the DB directly.

Comment: This will change your encryption key, will it not?

Comment: Is there any possibility that a "slow" shared server might be causing the problems? I ended up getting my site back (with no reinstall) by changing the core_config_data table for the unsecured url back to http://my-site.com/magento/ and and leaving the secured url blank. I have no idea why this works, but it does. In fact, even if I change it, it works but only for a few hours. I really would like to understand this issue but I am lost.

Comment: @philwinkle - you can always edit the `local.xml` and re-enter your old key though. We *never* use the installer as a 're-installer' - in fact, there's a debate going on about the use of it for that purpose [here](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/magento-enterprise-theme-fallback/). But given the OP's skillset, it seemed a more appropriate fix.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Very unlikely. But if you are aware your hosting is slow - why keep using it? There are some very good specialist hosting providers out there.

Comment: As soon as I realized that are some better options out there, I started doing the research. I am looking at either Aspiration Hosting or SiteGround (super cache?). One question - If I go with something like Magento Go that is hosted already, can I still edit core files to extend magento's classes, or do I not have access to the files on the server?

Comment: I know this sort of comment is not exactly following the rules, but I just had to do this :) +1 for Chuck Norris :D